# How to set only a cpu bar to be transparent in Conky?

Tags: conky, transparency

I need a transparent bar measure to improve my conky theme visual that's being created by me.Can anyone help me to solve this issue sharing a code for me please?Thanks! :)

Comment: I use the line: `own_window_argb_value 145  # semi-transparent`

Comment: Do you know if have a command like '$' to type before a specific code to turn it transparent and so control the opacity? Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing it's not possible to alter the transparency of a single element because as pointed out the transparency effect is for the **entire** window. So maybe you need to have the cpu bar in a window by itself with its own transparency.

Comment: @DK Bose I'de like if conky enable some smart code such I have mentioned.I think it is limited to us and it is not good. I don't know too if in python we can create amazing screens in conky but I've never works with this language before.Do you know about some website or ebook to learn python in conky? Thanks! :)

Comment: Why python? Conky is written in C and can be extended using Lua scripts. I don't think Python is relevant. You might want to read the Lua tutorial given on conky's github repository: https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki#tutorial

Comment: @terdon Thank you very much! I'll learn more about the most advanced script that I want to use creating my skin! I've said python cause I found a skin that have some skill that was written in python...However,as you recommended,I'll manage Lua scripts to know what it can do! :)

Comment: Perhaps you can create two conky windows? One normal and non-transparent, the other with transparent only elements?

Comment: @terdon Didn't realize you were a bigger conky geek than me. If you post an answer please ping me so I can up-vote :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix My idea is create just one window with all in one elements to make my work easier and smarter.I'm looking for a script that give me such a thing but I didn't find yet! I'm reading github tutorial that terdon recommended me. A crystal ball may be found there! I don't know...I'm just looking for a cpu bar that work like these: ( https://cn.pling.com/img/2/8/d/1/71b88109eec55305ec26142db4b8bb5e5a78.png)  (https://cn.pling.com/img/5/a/d/a/93844dc3d04e50ddbb6afefcaf5b6613a445.png)

Comment: I would be grateful if anyone help me to find a code to make my cpu bar work like these(square by square) cause I can't install them in my conky and the codes that I downloaded are broken!So the mystery carries on.It would save me a lot of time! Thanks! :)